# Unexpected end of file bash script

Tags: bash, shell

This is just a simple problem but I don't understand why I got an error here. This is just a for loop inside an if statement.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (!( -f $argv[1])) then
    echo "Argv must be text file";
else if ($#argv != 1) then
    echo "Max argument is 1";
else if (-f $argv[1]) then
    for i in `cut -d ',' -f2 $argv[1]` 
        do
        ping -c 3 $i;
        echo "finish pinging host $i"
    done
fi
```

Error is in line 16, which is the line after `fi`, that is a blank line .....

Can someone please explain why i have this error ????

Comment: To answer the literal question: `else if` is not the same as `elif`, because it leaves your first `if/then/else` block open while starting a second one, so you need _two_ `ends`, which is why you get the unexpected EOF.

Answer (score 2):

many, many errors.

If I try to stay close to your example code:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -f "${1}" ]
then
   echo "Argv must be text file";
else if [ "${#}" -ne 1 ]
     then
        echo "Max argument is 1";
     else if [ -f "${1}" ]
          then
             for i in $(cat "${1}" | cut -d',' -f2 )
             do
                ping -c 3 "${i}";
                echo "finish pinging host ${i}"
             done
          fi
     fi
fi
```

another way, exiting each time the condition is not met :

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "${#}" -ne 1 ] && { echo "There should be 1 (and only 1) argument" ; exit 1 ; }
[ ! -f "${1}" ] && { echo "Argv must be a file." ; exit 1 ; }
[ -f "${1}" ] && {
   for i in $(cat "${1}" | cut -d',' -f2 )
   do
      ping -c 3 "${i}";
      echo "finish pinging host ${i}"
   done
}
```

Comment: No reason for the extra curly brackets -- they serve no purpose when not parameterizing an expansion or disambiguating token boundaries.

Comment: ...and if you're going to use a `/bin/bash` shebang, might as well use bash operators: `else if (( $# > 1 ))` is easier to read.

Comment: ...and it's more efficient to not use cat; if you _must_ use cut: `cut -d, -f2 <"$1"`

Comment: @Charles: true, but i really prefer to teach standard (multi-shell) alternatives than bash specifics, whenever possible... portability is important. And taking the habit of putting the curly brackets helps when they do some `echo "${1}__bouh__"` in another script...

Comment: ...but the better approach would be not to use cut at all: `while IFS=, read _ address _; do ping -c 3 "$address"; done`

Comment: If you wanted to be portable, you'd use `#!/bin/sh` for your shebang; your script isn't portable anyhow as it's currently written.

Comment: As for "multi-shell", `(( ))` *is* multi-shell; it's available on bash, ksh and zsh right off the top of my head, and its close cousin `$(( ))` _is_ part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: (+1, by the way -- I may quibble, but this _does_ have a valid POSIX script [other than the shebang] as its outcome).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: on my (old) production servers (bash-2.05b), `((...)) is not recognized (but $((...)) is). My alternative is much older, hence could work on more systems.

Answer (score 0):

For every opening `if`, you must have a corresponding closing `fi`. This is also true for `else if`. Better use `elif` instead

```
if test ! -f "$1"; then
    echo "Argv must be text file";
elif test $# != 1; then
    echo "Max argument is 1";
elif test -f "$1"; then
    for i in `cut -d ',' -f2 "$1"` 
    do
        ping -c 3 $i;
        echo "finish pinging host $i"
    done
fi
```

- There's also no `argv` variable. If you want to access the command line arguments, you must use `$1`, `$2`, ...
- Next point is `$#argv`, this evaluates to `$#` (number of command line args) and `argv`. This looks a lot like perl.
- Furthermore, testing is done with either `test ...` or `[ ... ]`, not `( ... )`
- And finally, you should enclose at least your command line arguments in double quotes `"$1"`. If you don't and there is no command line argument, you have for example

  ```
  test ! -f
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  test ! -f ""
  ```

  This lets the test fail and go on to the second if, instead of echoing the proper message.

Comment: You have still errors in this script, but not `unexpected end of file`.

Comment: @TrungBún `argv` is the name of the array in C. In bash, it's referred to as `"$@"` (for the actual items), or `$#` (for their count). (`$*` is something different -- it behaves the same way as `$@` without quotes, which _is not_ guaranteed to evaluate back to the original argument vector).

Comment: @OlafDietsche `( ... )` does not invoke the test operator in bash (neither the built-in extended one nor the POSIX-compatible one), so this answer leaves in some very severe errors.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know, but one at a time. That's why I noted, this looks like perl. And OP hasn't even got the first one fixed and acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash -x

if [ ! -f "${1}" ]
    then 
    echo "Argument must be a text file."
else
    while-loop-script "${1}"
fi
```

I have broken this up, because I personally consider it extremely bad form to nest one function inside another; or truthfully to even have more than one function in the same file.  I don't care about file size, either; I've got several scripts which are 300-500 bytes long.  I'm learning FORTH; fractalism in that sense is a virtue.

```
# while-loop-script

while read line
    do
    IFS="@"
    ping -c 3 "${line}"
    IFS=" "        
done < "${1}"
```

Don't use cat in order to feed individual file lines to a script; it will always fail, and bash will try and execute the output as a literal command.  I thought that sed printing would work, and it often does, but for some reason it very often substitutes spaces for newlines, which is extremely annoying as well.

The only absolutely bulletproof method of feeding a line to a script that I know of, which will preserve all space and formatting, is to use while-read loops, rather than substituted for cat or for sed loops, as mentioned.

Something else which you will need to do, in order to be sure about preserving whitespace, is to set the internal field seperator (IFS) to something that you know your file will not contain, and then resetting it back to whitespace at the end of the loop.

Comment: Why are you changing `$IFS`? The only command here that pays attention to its value is `read`, and you can set IFS only for the duration of that one command rather than changing the shell value globally at all.

Comment: ...on a different note, your shebang would be more portably written as `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, with `set -x` on a separate line.

Comment: The file I was using as an example in order to work out this script, was a makefile I'd written a while back, and had tabs at the start of each line.  I discovered that changing IFS was the only way to preserve the starting tab, which in some situations I'd want.


Also, thank you for the bash line clarification.

Comment: I'd suggest `while IFS='' read -r line` in that case -- better to have no value for IFS set at all, and to scope the new value to the read. Alternately, leave off the `line` argument to `read`, and it'll ignore IFS altogether (and puts its parsed output in the variable `REPLY`). You'll still want `-r` -- otherwise, `read` tries to honor backslash-escapes, rather than giving content back to you exactly as it exists.